Flutter Navigation Error: Null check operator used on a null value when navigating to page V
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme!.primary,
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _showModalBottomSheet(context); // Pass context here
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void _showModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Modal Bottom Sheet',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  aboutnoteorfolder(
                    context,
                    arrowoperation: () {
                     
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return V();
                        },
                      ));
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Next'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}

void aboutnoteorfolder(
  BuildContext context, {
  required Function() arrowoperation,
}) {
  final AnimationController controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: Navigator.of(context),
    reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
  );
  showModalBottomSheet(
      elevation: 0,
      transitionAnimationController: controller,
      useSafeArea: true,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      barrierColor: const Color.fromARGB(90, 0, 0, 0),
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap:arrowoperation,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .955,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .65,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 128, 255),
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.0030,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(120, 255, 255, 255),
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.11,
                  )),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Navigate"
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
      });
}

class V extends StatelessWidget {
  const V({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}


**
My issue is that when the plus icon is pressed, a bottom sheet appears. Upon pressing the "Next" button in that bottom sheet, another blue sheet appears. When I press this blue sheet, I want to navigate to page V. However, I'm encountering the following error:
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
**

The root cause for this issue is:

builder gives you a context for the current modal bottom sheet (1)
then you pop this bottom sheet (2) -> cause this context is unmounted since it belongs to the bottom sheet, but now the bottom sheet was dismissed
finally, you re-use this context, which is unmounted (3) -> cause exception

Solution: you should use a different context instead of the bottom sheet context:

change the name of bottom sheet context to context2, so you code will using the context from params was passed to the function
or ignore it by using the syntax builder: (_) {...}



your analysis is correct but you by ignoring or renaming you push the the next bottomSheet using the context of the parent.  Wouldn't it be enough to just move the pop after the call to aboutnoteorfolder?

Yeah interesting questions, in most cases I assume it still works that way and does not throw exceptions, but I think shouldn't do that since Navigator.push is an async function, so code will go down immediately to the next line, nothing can sure 100%

void _showModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext ctx2) {
      return Container(
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Modal Bottom Sheet',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(ctx2);
                  aboutnoteorfolder(
                    context,
                    arrowoperation: () {
                     
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return V();
                        },
                      ));
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Next'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}

replace the code,
just set a diferent names for your buidlContext
in this case i've renamed the showModalBottomSheet context to ctx2
take a look at :https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html

But..When I press the 'Next' button, I want the first bottom sheet to pop up and move to the next blue sheet. Then, upon pressing to navigate, it should navigate to page V() and also pop that sheet

i understand,so i've update the answer
giving difrente name to buildContext,so you'll now what are you poppin* and when

wouldn't it be enough to do the pop after the call to aboutnoteorfolder?

Thanks, I got it. Could you explain what 'context' means in simple terms? I'm new to Flutter..

the context refers to the location of a widget in the widget tree. It provides information about the surrounding environment and services that the widget might need. For example, the context can contain information such as the theme of the app, the locale, the screen size, and more.  @Akshay
